# how to merge rows in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have table like below

```
PARTICULAR  OPENING TRANSACTION ENDING
Expense     5456456   0         0
Expense      0        1232131   0
Expense      0        0         123123
```

But I want to get the info like below

```
PARTICULAR  OPENING TRANSACTION ENDING
Expense     5456456  1232131    123123
```

Is it possible to achieve this using sql query?

Answer (score 5):

You want to `SUM` it up, I guess!

```
SELECT particular, 
       SUM(opening) AS total_opening, 
       SUM(transaction) AS total_transaction,
       SUM(ending) AS total_ending
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY particular
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT particular, 
       max(opening) opening, 
       max(transaction) transaction,
       max(ending) ending
  FROM your_table_name
 GROUP BY particular
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the transaction, opening and ending are greater than zero for just a row, the following would work

```
SELECT
   particular
   , MAX(opening) as opening
   , MAX(transaction) as transaction
   , MAX(ending) as ending
FROM 
  TBL_NAME
GROUP BY particular
```

In general, this documentation (of oracle's group by functions) might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/group-by-functions.html#function_max